# Where do i place the sin() formula for plane geometry to create a three.js particle wave?

Tags: three.js

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdDQY.png)im trying to create a particle wave effect in three.js , losing my mind as i tried different methods. anyone have an idea what i could do? my code is down below.

```
 // geomatry, material, mesh
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 5, 64, 64)

    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 'aqua', 
    size: 0.007})

    const particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    particles.rotation.x = 181;

    scene.add(particles);

    // Lighting
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2)
    light.position.set(2, 3, 4);
    scene.add(light);


    const render = function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render)
        
        
        //  particles.rotation.z += .005

        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const positions = geometry.attributes.position.array;
let k = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 3) {
        positions[i + 2] = Math.sin(((i+2)%(65*3)) / 20+k) * 0.5;
    }
    k+=0.1;
    geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}, 60);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you so much! :) it works but it seems like is going fast so im going to see if i can slow it down a bit.

Comment: if I need to change the wave direction from horizontal (right to left) to vertical (front to back) do i change the position length?

Comment: you kan rotation the plane , right is front。^_^